# Docker: tendermint container not work

Tags: docker, tendermint

My OS is Windows 10 and docker version `17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`.

Here is my plan:

**0.** Get containers

```
docker pull tendermint/tendermint
docker pull tendermint/monitor
```

**1.** Init container

```
docker run --rm -p 46657:46657 --name tendermint_bc -v "C:/Users/user/sandbox/tendermind/tmdata:/tendermint" tendermint/tendermint init
```

**2.** Start container

```
docker run --rm -d -v "C:/Users/user/sandbox/tendermind/tmdata:/tendermint" tendermint/tendermint node --proxy_app=dummy
```

**3.** Start tendemint monitor

```
docker run -it --rm --link=tm tendermint/monitor tendermint_bc:46657
```

By start of tendermint container I see only one hash, but by `docker ps -a` container is not listed.
If I run `docker logs tendermint_bc`, result is:

> Error response from daemon: No such container: tendermint_bc

Same workflow on Unix work fine.

Thx for help.

Comment: You may want to use compose for this

Comment: Now I used new Docker version.  
`18.03.0-ce build 0520e24`  
Command:  
`docker run --rm -p 46657:46657 --name tendermint_bc -v "C:/Users/user/sandbox/tendermind/tmdata:/tendermint" tendermint/tendermint node --proxy_app=dummy`  
Errors:  
`
panic: Panicked on a Sanity Check: Error initializing DB: sync /tendermint/data/blockstore.db: invalid argument
..vendor/github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/common.PanicSanity(0xb8b1c0, 0xc420988030)
`  
I know `Panicked on a Sanity Check: Error initializing DB: sync /tendermint/data/blockstore.db: invalid argument` but which argument is invalid?  
thx

Answer (score 0):

In step 1, you are initializing Tendermint, but not running it. To run it, execute:

```
docker run --rm -p 46657:46657 --name tendermint_bc -v "C:/Users/user/sandbox/tendermind/tmdata:/tendermint" tendermint/tendermint node --proxy_app=dummy
```

Comment: at step 2, I do not see `--name tendermint_bc`